# Open a file with unity c# in windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I creating a unity game and I the game has to open a .exe file in the assets of unity.

Answer (score 4):

This will open if .exe-file is in same directory as launchers .exe-file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("YourExeFileName.exe");
```

You can include `using System.Diagnostics` at the top of file to write it more easily:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
//...
Process.Start("YourExeFileName.exe");
```

This logs the dataPath so you can see where your applications should be:

```
Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);
```

This will open from the applications dataPath directory:

```
Process.Start($"{Application.dataPath}\\YourExeFileName.exe");
```

Optionally you can specify the full catalog name like this:

```
Process.Start("D:\\Unity projects\\MyGame\\Assets\\Scripts\\Scene 2\\MyExeName.exe");
```